# FTP using Access VBA creates file on server with no data

Tags: ms-access, ftp, vba

I am using the below function to upload the files to server using FTP.

But the file size is ZERO. The file contains no data. Can't figure out what error I made in implementing the function.

```
Function FTP_Data()
'=========================================================================
'FTP from Microsoft Access
'by Matthew V Carmichael
'Creates FTP Batch File, FTP command file (txt)
'========================================================================='
On Error GoTo Err_Trap

    Dim pFile As Long
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim ftpServer As String
    Dim strUserName As String
    Dim strPassword As String


    'Path and Name of file to FTP
    strPath = "C:\Temp\"
    strFileName = "C:\Temp\AccessDocumentation.pptx" 'Name of file to upload
    'FTP Server Settings
    ftpServer = "ftp.mydomain.com"
    strUserName = "user@mydomain.com"
    strPassword = "****"

    SetAttr strPath & "FTP_cmd.txt", vbNormal


    'Create text file containing FTP commands
    pFile = FreeFile
    Open strPath & "FTP_cmd.txt" For Output As pFile
    Print #pFile, "user"
    Print #pFile, strUserName
    Print #pFile, strPassword
    Print #pFile, "Put " & strFileName
    'Use the Put command to upload, use the Get command to download.
    'Print #pFile, "Get " & "Your File Name"
    Print #pFile, "quit"
    Close pFile

    'Create batch file to execute FTP
    pFile = FreeFile
    Open strPath & "FTP_Run.bat" For Output As pFile
    Print #pFile, "ftp -n -s:" & strPath & "FTP_cmd.txt " & ftpServer
    Print #pFile, "Pause"
    Close pFile

    SetAttr strPath & "FTP_cmd.txt", vbHidden

    'Execute FTP command
    Shell strPath & "FTP_Run.bat", 1


Err_Trap_Exit:
    Exit Function

Err_Trap:
    MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
    Resume Err_Trap_Exit

End Function
```

PS : New in VBA programming.

Comment: Will it run manually? Are you sure that it shouldn't read: ` strUserName = "user"`?

Comment: Yeah, first step should be to create a working FTP_Run.bat + FTP_cmd.txt, second step to create those via VBA (this should be the easy part).

Comment: @Andre I tried running it manually and found the same problem. Hence created another Question for the same - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743072

Comment: @Gustav The login is successful. See screenshot here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743072

Comment: I can see you got is sorted out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that there was problem in my PC itself. Could not find the exact cause of the problem though. I check firewall, there is no firewall issue as I turned it off and the issue was still there.

The above code works fine on other PC.

I am not deleting this Question, as other users might find this question and simple solution to the problem will be to try running the code on Other PC.

Another reason keeping this Q open is, This is ready made code for those who are searching for implementing FTP using Access VBA.