# Files created but, No data getting uploaded via using FTP in shell

Tags: shell, ftp, windows-shell

I am using command

`ftp -n -s:C:\FTP_cmd.txt ftp.madrecha.com`

the **FTP_cmd.txt** file contains

```
user
myName@domain.com
Pa$$Word
Put C:\AccessDocumentation.pptx
quit
```

The file is getting created on server. but, size is `0 bytes`. No data in the file. I tried using FileZilla to upload same file using same user. That was successful and file was created with 352 KB

Is there issue in the command or this is server side issue?

PS: I tried running using `cmd` (on windows) and also on `Powershell` (on windows). But resulted in same issue.

Thanks in advance.

UPDATE: Attaching screenshot of the command run.

[image: Command runs successfully]

Comment: I tried on another PC. the code is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have the reputation to comment at the moment, so I'm writing my guesses as an answer.

I think the "put" command has to be lowercase.
Additionally you should check the file permissions, you may have write access to the FTP server but no right to read from the file you want to copy to the server.

Comment: Also tried uploading a file from my desktop (just to be sure that I have access to that file. Still no difference.

Comment: I tried on another PC. the code is working. Thanks for the help

Comment: If you still have problems from the PC which you've tried earlier, you could check if the firewall is blocking something on port 21.